# Mimic Linux which command in C#

Tags: c#

I use a tool's binaries in a C# project called `GraphViz`. 
The problem is I must include the binaries path as hard-coded and I don't want to do that.

```
IRenderer renderer = new Renderer("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Graphviz2.38\\bin"); // todo: remove hardcoded GraphViz path
```

I want to mimic the linux `which` command.
Simply passing the binary name (e.g `dot`) and get the path.

```
GetBinaryPath("dot"); // return the above path
```

I'd appreciate any ideas or topics to start searching.

Note
Target OS: Windows 
.NET version : 4

Comment: why not use a flag? or a menu item? or an environment variable to specify where the program is installed or simply ensure that the binary is in your PATH variable and use exec without specifying the directory (which is what `which` does)

Comment: The 2 votes to close the question, I don't understand how this is not related to programming.

Comment: is the `Graphviz2.38` part fixed? if so you can get the `C:\\Program Files (x86)` via `Enviorment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, Not it's variable depending on the version of 3rd party tool

Comment: Also, Windows has a similar command line tool too, it is called `where`

Comment: On why this is a wonky question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to find path given only executable name (and installation directory is in your `PATH` environment variable)

*Option 1:*

Using `where` command with `Process` class. (test for exit code, parse the output)

*Option 2:*

You can get environment PATH environment variable, split it by ';' and test for your executable name existence.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find all directories where windows search for a exectuable file and that is from the environment variable %PATH%.
Then you need to find all extensions (.com, .exe, .bat etc) from %PATHEXT%.

Then you just check them like this:

```
internal class Program {
    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        if (args.Length != 1) {
            Console.WriteLine("Incorrect usage!");
            return;
        }

        var extensions = GetExecutableExtensions(args[0]);
        var paths = GetPaths();

        var exeFile = GetFirstExecutableFile(args[0], extensions, paths);
        if (exeFile == null) {
            Console.WriteLine("No file found!");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine(exeFile);
        }
    }

    private static string GetFirstExecutableFile(string file, string[] extensions, string[] paths) {
        foreach (var path in paths) {
            var filename = Path.Combine(path, file);
            if (extensions.Length == 0) {
                if (File.Exists(filename)) {
                    return filename;
                }
            }
            else {
                foreach (var ext in extensions) {
                    filename = Path.Combine(path, file + ext);
                    if (File.Exists(filename)) {
                        return filename;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static string[] GetExecutableExtensions(string file) {
        var data = GetCmdOutput("echo %PATHEXT%");
        var arr = data.TrimEnd('\n', '\r').Split(new [] {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        //If the command passed in ends with a executable extension then we dont need to test all extensions so set it to emtpy array
        foreach (var ext in arr) {
            if (file.EndsWith(ext, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                return new string[0];
            }
        }

        return arr;
    }

    private static string[] GetPaths() {
        var data = GetCmdOutput("echo %PATH%");
        return data.TrimEnd('\n', '\r').Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }

    private static string GetCmdOutput(string cmd) {
        using (var proc = new Process {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = "/c " + cmd,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            }
        }) {
            proc.Start();
            return proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just noticed the 'where' command in the answer from Skomialek. Much better solution. Well at least you know how it works from my code...